# SQLite Update all Columns values matching specific value

Tags: sql, sqlite, android-sqlite

Seems like a easy question but having some trouble finding the correct solution. How can I update values in a column that match a specific value?

Example.)

```
Table: Value Names

    |id| value | name  |
    --------------------
    |01| 12345 | bobby |
    |02| 12234 | anty  |
    |03| 12222 | jimmy |
    |04| 12345 | danny |
```

Replace value column where "12345" to "22222"

Comment: Hint:  `UPDATE`.  `WHERE`.

Comment: Have you tried this? `UPDATE table_name SET value = 22222 WHERE value = 12345;`

Comment: @GordonLinoff should be something like `UPDATE valuename
SET value= '2222',
WHERE value= 12345;` ?

Comment: your mentioned code is not running??

Comment: @AmrendraKumar I forgot to add the  '  between the values I wanted updated. *facepalm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer:
Forgot to add the ' between the values I wanted updated.

```
   UPDATE valuename SET value= '2222' WHERE value= '12345' ;
```